# console music player - parallel computing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, console-application, project

I'm a beginner python programmer and for my own training, i created a simple (Console) music player.
So the point and my main problem is I put a timer on this player but at the end of the song
the timer still continues without conclusion.

```
import playsound
import threading
import time
import datetime
import sys



def player(x):
    input_name = x
    filename = f"{input_name}"
    print("Playing: " + filename)
    playsound.playsound(f'{filename}')
    return str("end")


def timer(x):
    localtime = 73800
    while x != "end":
        result = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int(f"{localtime}")).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        print(result, end="")
        print("\r", end="")
        time.sleep(1)
        localtime += 1


def main():

    input_name = input("Please enter a file name: ")
    res = ""
    
    while True:
        if res == "end":
            sys.exit(0)
        p1 = threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(f"{res}",))
        p1.start()
        
        res = player(input_name)
        print(res)
        
    

main()
```

Comment: That's because there's nothing in your code to tell the thread to stop

Comment: After quick look, you are using RES to send parameter on timer, but if res=="end" you do sys.exit before send to timer. but timer expect that to end loop right?